# Why C# records do not generate parameter less constructor?

Tags: c#, .net

I was playing with C# records and it looks like declaration like this:

```
record Point (double X, double Y);
```

Will not generate a parameterless constructor. I like the concise syntax or records and the fact the all the boiler-plate code is shifted to the compiler.

is there a reason for records to not have parameterless constructors by default?
is there a way to instruct the compiler to generate a parameterless constructor in this case?

Comment: With a parameterless constructor you cannot guarantee that the fields have been set. Why do you need a parameterless constructor?

Comment: I was trying to use records with the Options pattern in ASP.NET core and when I do that IOptions complains that the class you use for strongly typed configuration has to have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: You could also declare a record like so `public record Point { public double X { get; set;} public double Y { get; set;} }` this will result in a mutable record with a parameterless constructor.

Comment: I don't really see much benefit to using a record with IOptions though.

Comment: I tought that records expand to something like : record  Point
{
 public Point (double x, double y) => (X, Y) = (x, y);

 public double X { get; init; }
 public double Y { get; init; }    
} 

and that the Options pattern will be able to use an object initializer to initialize the properties.

Comment: Object initializer syntax is just shorthand for creating an object using the default constructor, then assigning properties. So `new Point { X = 1, Y = 2 }` is not allowed either, and there is no (good) way for external classes to initialize records of unknown type, since they cannot reliably invoke the primary constructor (technically the mapping from constructor parameters to properties isn't guaranteed, though many do implicitly rely on this being "in order" of the properties being returned through reflection -- but this is an unreliable hack).